# Protobuf-net: Is it possible to generate a RuntimeTypeModel that is not mapped to concrete types?

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I have a web application that talks to a web service using protobuf. The service itself provides methods to get the .proto descriptors.

When I first tackled this the only protobuf library I found was protobuf-net (recently I have come across the protobuf-csharp-port, but I will get to that in a moment). Documentation for this library is quite limited and not having any prior knowledge of protobuf, the approach I initially took was to generate all my C# classes and enums automatically (via T4) applying the “ProtoContract” and “ProtoMember” attributes.

This worked fine but made my web application very brittle to changes. The web app acts as an interface to multiple versions of the web service that are under development, so gracefully handling change is a requirement.

Digging a little further I found how to generate a TypeModel dynamically and bind that to my pre-generated classes. e.g.

```
RuntimeTypeModel model = TypeModel.Create();

model.Add(typeof (MyClass), false).Add(1, "Id").Add(2, "Name");

TypeModel compiledModel = model.Compile();
```

This did successfully improve the robustness of the application to changes such as the addition or removal of optional fields (everything on the web service is optional in terms of its contract), but because I am still bound to a concrete type ('MyClass' in the example above) that are pre-generated, I am still susceptible to request / response model name changes.

So my question… is there a way with protobuf-net to generate a TypeModel that is not coupled to any concrete classes in my project?

I understand that the C++/Java/Python library by google supports (with dynamic messages?) this which is what the web service developers use, and why they have the expectation on me that renaming a class should not break my side, but currently it does.

In searching for a solution with protobuf-net I came across the protobuf-csharp-port project that is a closer port of googles and does appear to have the functionality I require (although I don’t really know how to achieve it at this point). So before undertake all the work to switch libraries I thought it would be prudent to check if what I require is possible in anyway with protobuf-net.

Is there any other way to tell the TypeModel which model to use to serialise / deserialise without it being bound to a concrete type? E.g. by name that I can get from the descriptors for the given version of the web server.

Thanks in advance for any help or advice.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your `MyClass` currently declared? Where is that coming from? To be clear: the protobuf format does not include names, so changing the names in different places won't matter; however, it is perfectly normal that *in your own code*, if you rename `MyClass` you will need to update all references to `MyClass`. The IDE tools usually help with this.

If you have descriptions, I'm not sure why you are configuring the class manually: wouldn't you just generate code (protogen) from the .proto and use that?

Comment: When I first started this I did not know there was a tool I could use to generate my classes in C# for use with protobuf-net, and in either case I had some specific requirements for the way they are generated that may even make the output of that tool less ideal than my current solution. I simply use T4 to spin through the class and enum message definitions and generate a .cs file for each. This way I can make the classes partial that allows me to add domain specific initialisation and properties to make the models I get from the web service a little nicer to work with.

Comment: So to answer your questions… My classes are declared in my domain class library that the projects references and use directly. They come from a manually triggered T4 template that fetches the message descriptors and generates the .cs files. Yes when the domain models are generated, any changes to class names will require that I update any references to those classes. However that’s not what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: During runtime if the web app talks to a web server that has a newer version with a renamed request message I will get the exception that the given message does not exist in the TypeModel. The reason it does not exist is because I will be unable to automatically match that to a model in my domain because it does not exist yet (I have to match them by name so it would not be able to match it to the old named class either).

Comment: So the reason I am asking if there is a way to build a RuntimeTypeModel without providing a concrete type is so that I would still be able to add these new messages even when I don’t have a model pre-generated in my domain to match it to.
This does raise the question how would I then tell the serialiser what message I wanted to try and serialise the provided object as. Which is why I suggested by name because its new name would be something I am aware of at runtime.

Comment: As I understand it, in the google version you do this by asking for a message instance by name that then you can push the values into. This decouples the classes used in the applications domain from the messages defined in the protobuf serialiser.

Comment: I realise this is a pretty odd set of requirement that come from a very particular way the web service developers want to work so I can understand if there is no solution to this, but if there is, it could save me quite a bit of time getting up to speed with protobuf-csharp-port so I thought it was worth asking the question.

Comment: @SteW the main thing that leaps to mind here is : if you know the name, look the type up via reflection (`Assembly.GetType(...)`) rather than `typeof`. That seems pretty similar...?

Comment: I only know the name of the new type that's in the RuntimeTypeModel that is generated on demand from the web service on first access. If renamed I will not know the now out of date name of the pre-generated model it was previously mapped to, unless actually I generate some sort of mapping history, e.g. method x request was called 'abc' when generated... now the descriptors say its 'cba'.

Comment: I can’t help but feel I am descending into an over complicated solution to get JSON like serialisation handling out of protobuf. What I mean by that is JSON’s ability to convert to and from object without being type strict, so just omitting properties that don’t match up.

Comment: I suppose another way of communicating what Im looking for without all the complicated specifics of my scenario is…
Can I serialise to and from an anonymous object? I imagine the answer is no, because how do I tell the serialiser what message to serialise to, without providing a type it knows about?

Comment: @SteW that really isn't a targeted scenario

Comment: Thats fair enough. Thank you very much for your help.